# How to write to a framebuffer in regl?

Tags: javascript, framebuffer, regl

I am trying to update the texture inside a framebuffer in REGL. But for some reason, it does not update the framebuffer.

here is the full code:

```js
const regl = createREGL({
  extensions: 'OES_texture_float'
})

const initialTexture = regl.texture([
  [
    [0, 255, 0, 255]
  ]
])

const fbo = regl.framebuffer({
  color: initialTexture,
  depth: false,
  stencil: false,
})

const updateColor = regl({
  framebuffer: () => fbo,
  vert: `
    precision mediump float;
  
    attribute vec2 position;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
 `,
  frag: `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0);
    }
 `,
  attributes: {
    // a triangle big enough to fill the screen
    position: [
     -4, 0,
      4, 4,
      4, -4
    ],
  },

  count: 3,
})

regl.clear({
  // background color (black)
  color: [0, 0, 0, 1],
  depth: 1,
});

updateColor(() => {
  console.log(regl.read())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regl/1.3.11/regl.min.js"></script>
```

- I set the `initialTexture` to green.
- In the `updateColor` command I specify the framebuffer making regl render to the framebuffer
- The fragment shader in `updateColor` renders a red color
- After the `updateColor` command has run, I expected the `initialTexture` to be red, but it stays green.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you provide a function to a regl command then you have to manually draw

```
updateColor(() => {
  regl.draw();   // manually draw
  console.log(regl.read())
});
```

I guess the point is if you provided a function then you're asking to customize stuff?

```js
const regl = createREGL({
  extensions: 'OES_texture_float'
})

const initialTexture = regl.texture([
  [
    [0, 255, 0, 255]
  ]
])

const fbo = regl.framebuffer({
  color: initialTexture,
  depth: false,
  stencil: false,
})

const updateColor = regl({
  framebuffer: () => fbo,
  vert: `
    precision mediump float;
  
    attribute vec2 position;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
 `,
  frag: `
    precision mediump float;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0);
    }
 `,
  // Here we define the vertex attributes for the above shader
  attributes: {
    // regl.buffer creates a new array buffer object
    position: regl.buffer([
      [-2, -2],   // no need to flatten nested arrays, regl automatically
      [4, -2],    // unrolls them into a typedarray (default Float32)
      [4,  4]
    ])
    // regl automatically infers sane defaults for the vertex attribute pointers
  },
  count: 3,
})

regl.clear({
  // background color (black)
  color: [0, 0, 0, 1],
  depth: 1,
});

updateColor(() => {
  regl.draw();
  console.log(regl.read())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regl/1.3.11/regl.js"></script>
```

As for how I found the answer I first checked that `drawArrays` and/or `drawElements` was being called by adding

```
WebGLRenderingContext.prototype.drawArrays = function() {
  console.log('drawArrays');
}
```

and similar for `drawElements` and I saw that it was never being called.

I tried the sample in the regl readme and it did.

Then I stepped though the code in the debugger, it wasn't that deep to see it never called drawXXX but if removed the function from `updateColor` it did call drawXXX. As for how to know that `regl.draw()` would fix it that was a guess. It is mentioned [in the docs](https://github.com/regl-project/regl/blob/gh-pages/API.md) but it's not clear that's what's right to do

Comment: Thank you! I can't find any documentation for `regl.draw()`. Where did you find out about it?